# How to whitelist IP addresses using boto3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-vpc

How can I use the boto3 library to whitelist VPC IP addresses? For example, if I want to whitelist traffic from an IP address `12.345.678.90` to a Postgres RDS instance running within a VPC on port 5432.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a sample way to whitelist traffic for an IP address that will connect to traffic on port 5432:

```
import boto3


ec2 = new_session.client('ec2', region_name='us-east-1')


ec2.authorize_security_group_ingress(
    GroupId='sg-123456',
    IpPermissions=[
        {
            'IpProtocol': 'tcp',
            'IpRanges': [
                { 'CidrIp': '12.345.678.90/32', 'Description': 'Test allowing ingress' }
            ],
            'FromPort': 5432,
            'ToPort': 5432,}
    ],
)
```